# insert list into dataframe for every row

Tags: python, arrays, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of metrics classifications that I am trying to write to a dataframe. 
So far, I have been able to write the precision, recall, and f1-score to the dataframe. However, I would like to add another column called models, that has the corresponding model to the precision, recall, and f1-score.

```
data = ((metrics.classification.precision_recall_fscore_support(clf3_expected, clf3_predicted)),
        metrics.classification_report(clf2_expected, clf2_predicted), 
        metrics.classification_report(clf1_expected, clf1_predicted))
data = np.array(data)
```

> array([ (array([ 0.86564351,  0.86185948]), array([ 0.86008561, 
>   0.86735779]), array([ 0.86285561,  0.86459989]), array([3738, 3762], dtype=int64)),
>          '             precision    recall  f1-score   support\n\n          0       0.85      0.85      0.85      3738\n          1       0.85
>   0.85      0.85      3762\n\navg / total       0.85      0.85      0.85      7500\n',
>          '             precision    recall  f1-score   support\n\n          0       0.71      0.72      0.71      3738\n          1       0.71
>   0.71      0.71      3762\n\navg / total       0.71      0.71      0.71      7500\n'], dtype=object)

```
model_lists = ['decision', 'bayes', 'log']

for row in concatenated.iterrows():
    concatenated.model = i
concatenated
```

Here is where I create my df:

```
columns = ['pos', 'neg',]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns )

df['model'] = 0
df
```

[image]
Then I group it by precision, recall, and support and create the model column

```
pieces = [df[:3], df[:3], df[:3]]
concatenated = pd.concat(pieces, keys=['precision', 'recall', 'suport', "model"])
concatenated
```

then, I want to insert the corresponding model name to the correct rows, however, I can only get it to write the last item in the list, which is log to the last column.

```
model_lists = ['decision', 'bayes', 'log']

for row in concatenated.iterrows():
    concatenated.model = i
concatenated
```

[image]

Instead of 'log' throughout the entire column it should be 'decision' , 'bayes', and  'log' and then repeat until the end of the the dataframe.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete.  Where are you defining `i` for example?  Where are you accessing the values in `model_list`?